# GuardMalloc shows unexpected EXC_BAD_ACCESS when inspecting variables

Tags: c++, opencv, guard-malloc

I enabled GuardMalloc to search a Bug in my Code. When running my Application it somehow shows me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` but when I look at the Variables There shouldn't be a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Here the Code:

```
for(i = -radius, k = 0; i <= radius; i++){

    int y = pt.y+i;
    if( y <= 0 || y >= img.rows - 1)
        continue;

    for(j = -radius; j <= radius; j++){

        int x = pt.x + j;
        if(x <= 0 || x >= img.cols - 1)
            continue;
        float dx = (float)(img.at<sift_wt>(y, x+1) - img.at<sift_wt>(y,x-1));
        float dy = (float)(img.at<sift_wt>(y-1,x) - img.at<sift_wt>(y+1,x)); //Throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS here.

        X[k] = dx; Y[k] = dy; W[k] = (i*i + j*j)*expf_scale;
        k++;
    }
}
```

The Values and variables look like this while the Error is thrown:

```
img.rows = 255
img.cols = 255
pt.x = 220
pt.y = 244
radius = 7
i = 7
j = -7
y = 251
x = 213
k = 210
```

I tried to use Guard Malloc, because I wanted to find the source of another `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` Error in another Method. Maybe this part of the Code is the Origin of this Error, but I don't know how to fix this one, because normally the Pointers are not accessing a Value out of the Matrix (`y-1 = 250` and `y+1 = 252` so still in the boundaries of the Mat).

**EDIT**
The variable `img` is a object from the type `cv::Mat` from opencv. So it is a 2D Matrix filled with information about a Image.

**EDIT2**
It seems, that the problem is caused by this part here: `img.at<sift_wt>(y+1,x);` with the first expression I dont get a Error.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what img is.

Comment: ups sorry for that I edit the Question with the explanation what kind of object `img` is @UKMonkey